# Unir dois array

Tags: php, array, array-associativo

Tenho um form com campos *produtos* e *quantidade* que são importados de nota fiscal:

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="form-group col-md-9">
      <label for="produto_nfe">Produto</label>
      <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="produto_nfe" name="produto_nfe[]" aria-describedby="" placeholder="predominância">
      <div class="produtos"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="quantidade_nfe">Qtd</label>
      <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="quantidade_nfe" name="quantidade_nfe[]" aria-describedby="" placeholder="X">
      <div class="quantidade"></div>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

Eles são passados via ajax com `$(form).serialize();` e como são varios campos, passo eles como um *array* para o php.

Utilize o seguinte codigo php para recepcionar:

```
$produtos = $_POST['produto_nfe'];
$quantidades = $_POST['quantidade_nfe'];
```

Quando dou um *var_dump* retorna o seguinte resultado:

Produtos:

```
array(3) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(5) "Toras" 
    [1]=> string(5) "Toras" 
    [2]=> string(5) "Toras" 
}
```

Quantidades:

```
array(3) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(9) "0.7600 M3" 
    [1]=> string(10) "29.5700 M3" 
    [2]=> string(10) "29.5700 M3" 
}
```

Preciso que esses campos sejam relacionados em um novo *array* para que eu possa adicionar no estoque, gostaria que ficasse desda maneira:

```
array(3) 
{ 
     NOME                QUANTIDADE
    [Toras]=> string(5) "0.7600 M3" 
    [Toras]=> string(5) "29.5700 M3" 
    [Toras]=> string(5) "29.5700 M3" 
}
```

Já tentei `array_combine`:

```
$produtos = $_POST['produto_nfe'];
$quantidades = $_POST['quantidade_nfe'];

var_dump(array_combine($produtos, $quantidades));
```

Porém só retorna um resultado:

```
array(1) 
{ 
    ["Toras"]=> string(10) "29.5700 M3" 
}
```

Como poderia ser feito para que se mantivesse todos os produtos relacionados com a quantidade?

Comment: Os dois arrays sempre terão o mesmo tamanho certo? E sempre o de quantidade seguirá a ordem do que informa os produtos?

Comment: Faz um `for` ou `foreach` e crie um novo `array` é a maneira boa de se fazer ... mas, um pergunta porque unir, se precisa fazer o que ?:

Comment: Da maneira como você quer que fique não dá, você não pode repetir chaves na array.

Comment: Gustavo faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) você tem perguntas abertas no site, dá uma olhada como deve agir aqui ...

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel sempre terão o mesmo tamanho, é feito uma pré verificação.

Comment: Fica complicado lhe dar uma resposta, pois estive vendo seu histórico de perguntas e você não vota e nem aceita as respostas para suas perguntas.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Preciso colocar na base de dados cada produto, então se tenho no patio "toras de eucalipto" e tem "30 MB" quando lançar a nota fiscal ele vai relacionar "numero da nota fiscal" "produto" "quantidade". como você deu a dica de utilizar um loop, eu tentei de todas as maneiras e confesso que andei em circulos e nada.

Comment: Sem resolver o comentário do @bfavaretto não há como responder. O que você pede é impossível de fazer, dado que um array associativo não pode ter chaves iguais.

Comment: @bfavaretto entendo, Obrigado pela sinceridade heheh.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Perdão, não é minha intenção ofender a comunidade, estarei revendo meu modo de agir! obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @GustavoLucksik, como bfavaretto já explicou não tem como deixar do jeito que você quer devido a restrição da chave do array associativo.  Porém dá para deixar os dados em outros formatos. É interessante para você uma resposta que o array esteja em outro formato que não seja o que especificou na pergunta?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sem duvidas é interessante, se você poder lucidar, serei grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como foi explicado nos comentários o formato de array desejado não é possível de ser alcançado pois em PHP um array associativo não pode ter chaves repetidas. A tentativa de adicionar uma chave repetida resulta em sobrescrição do último valor inserido.

Como foi especificado, nos comentários, que ambos os array terão o mesmo comprimento possibilidade é rearranjar os dados e um array onde cada elemento possua um `id` vindo do array `$produtos` e a quantidade vinda do array `$quantidade`:

```
<?php

$produto = ["Toras", "Toras", "Toras"];

$quantidade = ["0.7600 M3", "29.5700 M3", "29.5700 M3"];

$romaneio = [];

foreach(range(0, count ($produto) - 1) as $i){
  $romaneio[] = ["id"=> $produto[$i], "quantidade" =>$quantidade[$i]];

}


print_r($romaneio);
```

Que resulta no seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => Toras
            [quantidade] => 0.7600 M3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => Toras
            [quantidade] => 29.5700 M3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => Toras
            [quantidade] => 29.5700 M3
        )

)
```

Código funcionando no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/NotableCapitalDatalog

Comment: Funcinou perfeitamente, inclusive vou utilizar em outras partes do meu codigo, realmente me ajudou nessa charada!